# How i can solve error null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I cannot add a new item to the database. An error appears that the **user** field is not added. I get error *null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint* What is mean? How could I solve this problem?

**models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    user =  models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='User', on_delete=models.CASCADE) #models.IntegerField(blank=True)
...
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user=serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model=Account
        fields='__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # address_data = validated_data.pop('address')
        # address = Address.objects.create(**address_data)
        # validated_data['address'] = address
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            if self.context['request'].method in ['GET']:
                self.fields['members'] = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        except KeyError:
            pass
            
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__' #('id', 'name', 'description', 'date_created', 'user', 'status', 'theme', 'members')
        
    def get_members(self, obj):
        accounts = Account.objects.filter(id__in=obj.members)
        return AccountSerializer(accounts, many=True).data
        
class CompanyListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # memb = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='members.user')
    class Meta: 
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Check what setting you have regarding null in your `models.py`. (And if you change it, make sure to make and run the migrations.) Or if you don't want to permit null then fix whatever bit of code is trying to add it without a value.

Comment: This means that I need to override POST in the __init__ method and set a new value for user_id? https://dropmefiles.com/DeHyX

Answer (score 1):

An object in your user table (not provided) may violate the primary constraint `user_id`. You should try to access your database manually (if the data is valuable) and add some value to this field in all related entries.

You user table should generate a primary constraint e.g. `user_id` when generating the object otherwise you will need to provide it.

The serializer isn't working because your ORM is no accepting an entry (without `user_id`) that's violating the schema.

Comment: How i can do it? ) I think I need to add the correct value to the user_id field. In table https://dropmefiles.com/DeHyX

Comment: It seems like there's no `user_id` field in this table. Please provide the `User` Table